# Write json object values without { ": , using c#

Tags: c#, json, formatting

```
{

"FirstName" :"Kaustubh",
"LastName" :" Sawant ",
"StartTime" :"01:00:00"

}
```

I want to get printed

```
First Name: Kaustubh
Last Name: Sawant
Start time : 01:00:00
```

This is the demo code written the actual object retrieves more values.
Actual code :

```
String JsonValue=JsonConvert.SerializsObject(object);
```

also used `Formatting.Indented` and tried

```
Regex.Replace(JsonValue,@"\{},"","").Trim();
```

and then wrote into file using `StreamWriter`.

Comment: When you remove the `{` it will no longer be a JSON. But this is not the problem. To help you, we need to know your code. How do you write the output? When you use a third party library/function, it may be impossible to alter the output without changing the code of the library. And your sample output has a totally different style. It would be better to make a custom "Save" function.

Comment: i have converted the json object to string ,perform formatting.indented.I just want write the object without { " : , because i m going to send this text file to user.I have use newtonsoft.json

Comment: You might be able to do this with a custom `JsonWriter` similar to the ones shown in [Custom JSON Derivative Format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30610196/3744182) or [JsonConverter Keyvalues with = instead of : separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48267668/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are attacking this from the wrong angle, if this is truly *json*, you are best to deserialize it using something like *json.net*, and then building the string up out of the properties.

However, because you insist on doing it via replacement, you can make use of *regex*

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[,{}\"")]", "").Trim();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
FirstName :Kaustubh
LastName : Sawant 
StartTime :01:00:00
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xhEZan)

Comment: I get the output properly but it is displayed in one line

Answer (score 0):

Considering json is a string variable containing your input:

```
var json = @"
{
""FirstName"" :""Kaustubh"",
""LastName"" :"" Sawant "",
""StartTime"" :""01:00:00""
}";
```

Simple solution relying on standard library:

```
Console.WriteLine(json.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Replace("\"","").Replace(",", "").Trim());
```

A solution using Newtonsoft.Json framework for deserializing json string:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

foreach (var entry in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Key}: {entry.Value}");
}
```

Comment: String jsonValue= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, Formatting.Indented); I have use this the output is the json object which is written in file.I want to structurized the written content into file,So that I could sent this file to user via email.

Comment: If you have a user object and want to put it in an email, then maybe you don't need json, but proper text or html formatting depending on how you want or email. You could use StringBuilder to create a html table with one or more users.

Comment: I don't want to put a user object in email but sort and  retrieve data and store on file and send it to user. The object retrieves the values of appointment details such as timing, problem,description,date etc he has taken.