# How to convert JSON format plain text to simple plain text

Tags: c#, json

I have a string in plain text which contains brackets like JSON format as it is created using JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize() method. I need to remove brackets and collon and want to convert it into key = value, key = value format.
Need to convert

```
{
     "account":"rf750",
     "type":null,
     "amount":"31",
     "auth_type":"5",
     "balance":"2.95",
     "card":"re0724"
}
```

to

```
'account=rf750,type=null,amount=31,authe=5,balanc=2.95,card=re0724'
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your output example isn't consistent.  Please clarify.

Comment: Seems a bit similar to [JsonConverter Keyvalues with = instead of : separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48267668/3744182).

Answer (score 4):

Well, you've got three different things going on here.

**The first, and surface issue, is: how do you change the string?**

Simple - you do some string substitutions, preferably using Regex.  Remove the starting/ending braces, change [a]:"[b]", to [a]=[b], - or however you want the final format to look like.

**The second, and slightly deeper issue is: JSON isn't just a simple list of keys=values.**  You can have nesting.  You can have non-string data.  Simply saying you want to change the JSON result to key=value,key=value,key=value, etc - is *fragile*.  How do you know the JSON structure will be what you're expecting?  JSON Serialization will serialize successfully even if you've got nested structures, non string/int data, etc.  And if you want solid code that doesn't easily break, you have to figure out: how do I handle this?  *Can* I handle this?

**The third, and final thing is: you're taking a *standard* data format schema and figuring out how to translate it to a *nonstandard* data format.**  90% of the time someone does that, they deserve to be shot.  Seriously, spend some solid time asking yourself whether you can use the JSON *as-is*, and whether the process wanting key=value,key=value,etc can be changed to use an actual *standardized* data format.

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple solution which (1) parses json to `Dictionary` and (2) uses [String.Join](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=string.join&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) and Linq [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) to provide desired output:

```
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
..
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
var str = string.Join(',', dict.Select(r => $"{r.Key}={r.Value}"));
```

`str`-variable now contains:

```
account=rf750,type=,amount=31,auth_type=5,balance=2.95,card=re0724
```

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks everyone for your time and response. your answer led me towards solution and finally i found the following solution which resolved the issue perfectly.

```
var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(modelString);

modelString = String.Join("&",jObj.Children().Cast<JProperty>().Select(jp => jp.Name + "="+ HttpUtility.UrlEncode(jp.Value.ToString())));
```

the above code converts the JSON into a url encoded string and remove the JSON format